# Vertically aligning the center of text and images

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align text of different sizes and images in-line.  I'd like the center of the text to be aligned, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

Here's a minimal example with some attempts:

[image]

Here's the code that generated that image:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         
\usepackage{graphicx}                                                           
\usepackage{array} % for tabular m{...}                                         
                                                                                
\begin{document}                                                                
                                                                                
\begin{center}                                                                  
  \Huge LEFT \normalsize                                                        
  \includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-a}                                  
  RIGHT                                                                         
\end{center}                                                                    
                                                                                
\begin{center}                                                                  
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1ex}                                                   
  \begin{tabular}[c]{r c l}                                                     
    \Huge LEFT &                                                                
    \includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-b} &                              
    RIGHT                                                                       
  \end{tabular}                                                                 
\end{center}                                                                    
                                                                                
\begin{center}                                                                  
  \Huge LEFT \normalsize                                                        
  \raisebox{-0.75em}{\includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-c}}              
  \raisebox{0.4em}{RIGHT}                                                       
\end{center}                                                                 
                                                                                
\begin{center}                                                                  
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1ex}                                                   
  \begin{tabular}{ m{0.3\textwidth} m{4em} m{0.3\textwidth} }                   
    \raggedleft \Huge LEFT &                                                    
    \includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-a} &                              
    \raggedright RIGHT                                                          
  \end{tabular}                                                                 
\end{center}                                                                    
                                                                                
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the `\raisebox{lift}[height][depth]{text}` is the best way for short snippets like in your example. For longer text, perhaps `\parbox[pos]{width}{text}` would be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a text wrapper around the `\vcenter` primitive (which is basically what also `adjustbox` dos internally). A starred form ignores the depth of the content.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textvcenter}{\@ifstar{\@tempswatrue\text@vcenter}{\@tempswafalse\text@vcenter}}
\newcommand*{\text@vcenter}[1]{\mbox{$\m@th\vcenter{\setbox\z@=\hbox{#1}\if@tempswa\dp\z@\z@\fi\box\z@}$}}

% to show the axis height in the snapshot
\newcommand*{\showmathaxis}{%
   \setbox\z@=\hbox{$a$}%
   \@tempdima\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax
   \@tempdimb\@tempdima
   \advance\@tempdima.2\p@
   \advance\@tempdimb-.2\p@
   \leavevmode\rlap{\vrule height\@tempdima depth-\@tempdimb width10cm}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\showmathaxis
\textvcenter{\Huge LEFT }%
\textvcenter{\includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-a}}
\textvcenter{RIGHT}
\textvcenter{qypgjtl}
\textvcenter*{qypgjtl}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also a nice solution since it needs no additional packages to be loaded. I also tried lowercase letters with your approach, like suggested by @JohnKormylo. They're centred including the length of the descenders for calculating the vertical middle of the line (option `valign=m` in my answer). Is there an easy solution for calculating the vertical alignment without taking the length of the descenders into account? If not, no problem, since this is not my question post ;)

Comment: @lukeflo See edit.

Comment: looks great. If someone chooses your plain approach or my with the `adjustbox` solely depends on personal preferences. The latter may offer more options, the former has lesser conditions. For me personally, your approach was a very interesting example in plain TeX regarding a field I'm not very used to (depth of characters/letters). So at least in my case, something learned again. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `adjustbox` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{atbegshi,picture}
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \put(\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin+.5\textwidth\relax,-\paperheight\relax){%
            \line(0,1){\paperheight}%
        }%
    }%
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{1em}
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{\adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge LEFT} \includegraphics[width=4em,valign=m]{example-image-b} \adjustbox{valign=m}{RIGHT}}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I only used `\vspace` and `\fbox` to illustrate that the text is vertically and horizontally centered. Just leave it out in your document. Plus I added a vertical line in the middle of the text area for orientation.

But to be honest its a lot of typing just for centering three different words/images. Maybe you could wrap it into a new command.

**Edit**

As John Kamylo pointed out, there is a difference when you use lowercase letters with descenders like g, y or p. It is possible to substitute `valign=m` with `valign=M`. The former will include the depth of the descenders for calculating the centre, the latter will take the general baseline of the letters as reference. You can try out which fits your needs better.

I myself would prefer `M` option. Looks better in my eyes ;)

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is a subtle difference beteen [valign=m] and [valign=M], at least if there are descenders.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's true. I tested both options and in this particular case I can see no real difference. If you see a one, your eyes have to be much sharper than my ;)

Comment: Try "pygmy" instead of "TEST"..

Comment: Thanks for the hint. And you're right again. Maybe my answer was a little bit unprecise in this regard. But the OP offered only capital letters. If he wants/needs lowercase letters is unclear. And if yes, we still don't know, how he wants them to be vertically centered: descenders in- or excluded. Maybe he will tell us :)

Comment: Just edited my answer to include your comment.

Comment: I used all caps in my question only because it was easy to demonstrate centering.  But indeed I will be using some lower-case.  Good tips on the `m` vs `M` to account for that.